# Inyección de URL

Tags: wordpress, google-search-console

Desde hace unos días Google ha calificado mi página web como sitio comprometido debido según a su Search Console a una inyección de URL (estas páginas parecen haber sido creadas por un hacker con la intención de realizar prácticas fraudulentas en los resultados de búsqueda).

La URL en cuestión es: http://nohagasnada.com/wp-admin/one-piece-spring-276.html y su última detección el día 13/2/16

No encuentro el archivo en la carpeta wp-admin dentro del FTP. Utilizo Wordpress con pocos plugins y siempre actualizado todo a la última versión, incluyendo Wordfence.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar el problema para limpiar la inyección y que Google vuelva a mostrar mi sitio como seguro?

Comment: Sucuri dice que no hay nada, a lo mejor ya solucionaste el problema? https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/

Comment: Hola Inigo. ¿Quedo solucionado el problema? En caso contrario, te podría servir https://developers.google.com/webmasters/hacked/